# How do I keep animated links underlined for the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a nav menu where the links are underlined on hover. When the link is clicked I want the underline to remain, and not animate again for the current page.

Here's is what I have so far.

```
header ul li a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
    margin: 14px 0px 0px 0px;
}

header ul li a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;

}
```

This code will add the underline when a link is hovered. I've tried keeping the link underlined for the current page with javascript, but it doesn't produce the desired affect.

```
document.getElementById('contact-link').style.borderBottom = '3px solid 
white'; 

document.getElementById('contact-link').style.paddingBottom = '0px';
```

Here is an example for want I'm trying to accomplish.
https://rocketlabusa.com/

Comment: You probably want to use the CSS pseudo class ```a:visited```

Answer (score 2):

I works if you add a class on click...

```js
$("header ul li a").on("click", function(){
  $(this).addClass("visited");
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
}

header ul li a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
    margin: 14px 0px 0px 0px;
}

header ul li a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
}

header ul li a.visited:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <ul>
    <li>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679020/how-do-i-keep-animated-links-underlined-for-the-current-page" target="blank">hello</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: This is what I want but it's not working on my end at all.

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Comment: No I don't. Gonna keep trying here. It's like the JavaScript isn't being read.

Comment: 1) You have to load the jQuery library 2) If you placed the script in document's head, wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function(){...}`

Comment: I can't do more.  I can't guess anything else without clues.

Comment: Works perfectly when I do <a>hello</a> instead of <a href="hello">hello</a>. I see the problem now. The class is being removed once the page is reloaded.

Comment: If the link loads a new page, sure, this effect can't stay. I tought you where using ajax to load the page content (below the header) or a show/hide div trick. Much like in the example you provided. So how to do this is another question. Look for ajax, there is a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Add following CSS at the end:

```
header ul li a:visited {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```